# Check if AmazonS3Client connection is active or not

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm using AmazonS3Client in java, i want to test if my client is connected or not, i read in forum that we should use:

`s3Client.listBuckets();`

The problem is that i do not have the permission to use this function where i work.

Any other solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Testing whether your client is "connected" is meaningless when it comes to AWS, since all requests are based on HTTP. Unlike a database, there isn't a persistent connection (at least as far as you should care). What is the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: hi, i want to handel the exception/problem if my client is disonnected..

Comment: As I said, that's meaningless.

Comment: @Parsifal He is right. If you implement a try-catch block it will automatically come to catch and show you the error that there is some AWS connection issue. So you don't need to implement it separately.